# "On a scale" vs "over a scale"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between "something acts on a scale" vs "something acts over a scale"?

Ex.

- A force that acts on a large scale.
- A force that acts OVER a large scale.

Comment: Is it "on a scale" or "on a large scale"? They're not the same thing.

Comment: I think something like ***gravity*** "acts ON a large scale", meaning that the effect of gravity is *only* really apparent at "large, macroscopic" scales. Unlike the ***strong nuclear force***, which only really acts on a microscopic / subatomic level. That's to say, those two forces each have ***specific, limited scope*** "scales, sizes" within which their actions are significant. On the other hand, if I'm told something "acts OVER a large scale", I would assume the intended meaning is more along the lines of ***has noticeable effects at ALL scales*** (or ***across a wide range*** of scales).

Comment: That is what I expected, just wanted to verify. Thanks @killingTime.